# proof that L is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Given that $A$ is a regular language and $B$ a regular or non-regular language, prove that $L$ is regular:

$$L = \{w | wx \in \text{A such that }x \in B\}$$

We can say that L is a subset of A. Regular languages are not closed under subsetting and I can't find a way to prove that this subset is regular regardless of B.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is a quotient, not a subset. $L$ is not a subset of $A$, in general.

Answer (score 1):

- Let $A$ be a regular language and let $B$ be any language.
- Because $A$ is regular, there's a deterministic finite automaton that accepts $A$. Let $M$ be one such machine, with a set of states $Q$ and set of accepting states $F\subseteq Q$.
- It is possible to modify the machine $M$ to make a machine that accepts the quotient language $L=\{w \;|\;  \exists x : wx\in A\wedge\, x\in B  \}$.
- Indeed, for any state $q\in Q$ and any arbitrary string $x\in \Sigma^*$, let $\delta(q, x)$ denote the state that $M$ is in after it starts from the state $q$ and reads the string $x$.
- Define a new machine $M^\prime$ which is exactly like $M$ except it has a new set $F^\prime$ of accepting states. The new accepting states are $$F^\prime \equiv \bigcup_{x \in B } \{q \in Q : \delta(q,x) \in F\}.$$

  In other words, we consider each state $q$ in turn. We imagine feeding each string $x\in B$ into the machine starting from state $q$. If the machine ends up in an accepting state after reading some string $x$, then $q$ should be marked as an accepting state in the new machine. Otherwise, $q$ should be marked as a non-accepting state in the new machine.
- This new machine $M^\prime$ accepts the language $L$. It is a deterministic finite automaton, so $L$ is a regular language.
- Note that this proof is nonconstructive—if $B$ is a very complicated language, it may be difficult or impossible to *compute* the set of states $F^\prime \subseteq Q$.  Nonetheless, $F^\prime$ exists as a well-defined subset of $Q$. It exists even if we cannot confirm what it is, and so the machine $M^\prime$ exists, even if we cannot confirm what it is.

See: [Quotient of a regular language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13771/quotient-of-a-regular-language)